# Unity 3d iOS inapp transaction raw data

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, verification

for verification matters I need some data from iOS SKPaymentTransaction

transactionIdentifier  property
 transactionDate  property
 transactionReceipt
 originalTransaction.transactionIdentifier
 originalTransaction.transactionDate

(see [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

I tried Prime31 StoreKit plugin, but it doesn't have what I need: [prime31 class](http://take.ms/Wt6wN)

So how can I get access to those properties? 
Which ways or other plugins can you suggest?